# Lambda Python Copy from Folder in one S3 Bucket to the Root of another S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I currently have a lambda that extracts a zip file to an s3. I would like to be able to go into the folder created by the extracted zip and copy the contents (all files and folders of the extracted zip folder) to another s3 bucket

Example:

from
`src_bucket/extract/*`

to
`dest_bucket/*`

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this in the same lambda function?

Comment: not necessarily no - The extract is is triggered by the zip upload to the bucket.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a specific problem? You can simply use [list_objects_v2 - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html) to list the objects in the bucket, then loop through them and call [copy_object - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/copy_object.html) to copy them to the other bucket. Or, since you already have an AWS Lambda function that unzips and uploads to S3, have it upload to the other bucket at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I can do something like this but it takes the entire folder and not the folder contents

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Create an S3 client
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # Specify the source and destination bucket names
    source_bucket_name = 'mybucket'
    destination_bucket_name = 'mybucket2'

    # List objects in the source bucket
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket_name)

    # Iterate through the objects in the source bucket
    for obj in response['Contents']:
        key = obj['Key']
        
        # Check if the object starts with "myfolder"
        if key.startswith('myfolder'):
            # Copy the object to the destination bucket
            copy_source = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': key}
            s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=key, CopySource=copy_source)
```

Comment: Also `list_objects_v2` is limited to 1000 objects. im at 833 but could go over this in future

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get is working with the following code. I had to use the split, to then delete the first folder name and rejoin.

```
# Create an S3 client
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# Specify the source and destination bucket names
source_bucket_name = 'mybucket'
destination_bucket_name = 'mybucket2'

# List objects in the source bucket
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket_name)

# Find the folder containing the word "myfolder" in its name
folder_name = None
for obj in response['Contents']:
    key = os.path.splitext(obj['Key'])[0]
    print(key)
    
    # Check if the object is a folder containing the word "simply" in its name
    if 'myfolder' in key:
        folder_name = key
        break

if folder_name is not None:
    # List objects in the folder
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Prefix=folder_name + '/')

    # Iterate through the objects in the folder
    for obj in response['Contents']:
        key = obj['Key']

        # Skip the folder itself
        if key == folder_name + '/':
            continue

        # Extract the filename and folders by removing the root folder
        filename = key.split('/')
        del filename[0]
        filename = "/".join(filename)

        # Copy the object to the root folder of the destination bucket
        new_key = filename if len(filename) > 0 else 'default_filename'
        copy_source = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': key}
        s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=new_key, CopySource=copy_source)
```